# Setup wiped Polycom phone without SIP server

Tags: voip, polycom

I'm troubleshooting a Polycom SoundPoint IP 550. I have wiped the hard disk of the phone (via a menu option) and now it's stuck in a reboot cycle. Apparently the only way to setup the firmware of the phone is to use a boot server.

Does anyone know another way to setup the phone/firmware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the boot process should be the following:

1. phone starts and asks DHCP server for IP
2. DHCP server gives the phone the address of the boot server via option tftp-server-name
3. phone retrieves necessary files from boot server via http/ftp

The boot server is just an ordinary http/ftp server. It can be the same (Linux) box as the DHCP server. The difficult part could be getting all the files necessary. There's a some (possibly confusing and outdated) info on [voip-info.org](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Polycom+Phones), and you could also google for 'polycom auto-provisioning'.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't think there is any way to use a boot server, however, why not simply setup a tftp server on your laptop?

Simply download a TFTP client, such as http://www.solarwinds.com/products/freetools/free_TFTP_server.aspx

Connect your phone to your router or to your PC and force it to have an IP address, then connect your TFTP software to that IP, download the Polycom drivers from polycom.com, and you should be able to transfer accross the new bootloader software allowing you to restore the phone back to factory settings.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the neat idea, but I don't see where in the phone settings where to point it towards the TFTP server setup on my machine.

Comment: Justin - it's in the bootloader menu, the one that appears shortly after powering on the phone.